# Flink 1.4 Could not retrieve BlobServer address

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm getting the following exception when using Flink 1.4, JDK 1.8.0_151, with Kafka and table query.  From the log it looks like the BlobServer starts and then shuts down.  I have a feeling that it has to do with missing dependencies?

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-table_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-runtime_2.11:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-client-java__2.11:1.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:+'
}
```

My Exception when I run it inside intellij:

```
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  JobClient:326 - Job execution failed
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  FlinkMiniCluster:433 - Stopping FlinkMiniCluster.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  JobSubmissionClientActor:337 - Terminate JobClientActor.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  JobSubmissionClientActor:315 - Disconnect from JobManager Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#587536570].
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  TaskManager:128 - Stopping TaskManager akka://flink/user/taskmanager_1#259478943.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  TaskManager:128 - Disassociating from JobManager
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  PermanentBlobCache:225 - Shutting down BLOB cache
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  TransientBlobCache:225 - Shutting down BLOB cache
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  IOManager:110 - I/O manager removed spill file directory /tmp/flink-io-01a605f7-0df5-4494-8acf-cbea6dfa90ee
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  NetworkEnvironment:341 - Shutting down the network environment and its components.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  TaskManager:128 - Task manager akka://flink/user/taskmanager_1 is completely shut down.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  JobManager:128 - Stopping JobManager akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1.
2018-01-11 09:23:36 AM INFO  BlobServer:364 - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:46717
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Could not retrieve BlobServer address.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor$1.call(JobSubmissionClientActor.java:166)
at akka.dispatch.Futures$$anonfun$future$1.apply(Future.scala:97)
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete log of the failing run?

Comment: Here are the log files along with my code: https://gist.github.com/xuan/e6d4543c478c30d5747428589b03dd03  My code works when I deploy it on a flink server but fails when I run it in my intellij.  What's the best way to run my code within an IDE without having the generate uber jar and deploy every time?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8485 because I only have 1 core processor.